# Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver' not found error

Tags: eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm getting this error with my Spring MVC sample application using Spring STS Eclipse plugin:

> Class
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver'
>   not found [config set: webninar-hello/web-context]servlet-context.xml

Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a refreshing problem.

F5, Cleanup Project, F5, Server Clean, maybe Server Clean Working directory.

If this all does not help. Remove the application from the server (close the window) and then add it again.

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I remembered to install m2e Maven plugin. http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem with a mistake in my maven configuration. As Ivan mentioned in his answer `org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar` was not at my lib directory. So I searched for it's maven dependency from http://blog.springsource.org/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/ URL.

Then I realized I included wrong dependency in my pom.xml
correct dependency as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Previously I had `spring-web` as the artifactId. Hope this helps :)

Comment: In case you have this issue and you already have `spring-webmvc` added, just remove it and add it again. That fixed an issue in my case.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and it wasn't a refreshing problem for me. I had to add the following jar to my build path:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
```

You can download the Spring bundle from the Spring website: http://www.springsource.org/spring-community-download

Comment: this worked for me as well. Why is no answer marked as correct?

Answer (score 2):

Just clean the project and check this dependency in  your POM.xml file 
Definitely it will work fine.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I deleted everything under /Users//.m2/repository with rm -R * and then rebuilt everything with Maven>>Update Project, closed and reopened project, cleaned project and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add following dependencies to pom filefor resolve this issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```